# Set different text on Push notification when device is locked

Tags: ios, ios7, push-notification

Hope you all will be fine.

I am facing a small problem related to how to set different text on push notification when device is locked. I am attaching image to illustrate. [image]

Here in the pic you can see that text written below the alert of push notification is **slide to answer**. While when I sent push notification to another they get **slide to view**

So my question is how can we change it because the device is locked and we don't have any access to push notification. Only web server and OS have access to that push.

Do you people have any suggestion how to do this?

**Thanks-**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a push notification you can specify the action by using a [dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW20) rather than a string as the alert payload.  The `action-loc-key` specifies the "action" text to use instead of "view"

For a local notification you can set the [`alertAction`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/alertAction) property of a `UILocalNotification` to change the text.

So if you set the `action-loc-key` (APNS) or `alertAction` property (`UILocalNotification`) to "answer" you will get "slide to answer".

Another approach, rather than using push notification, is to use the [VoIP facilities](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW12) in iOS. By setting your sockets into "VoIP mode", iOS will notify your app when a call is received, and you can then push the local notification to the screen if necessary.

Comment: @Paulw11- I am not using local push notification. So it is posible to do this without using this?

Comment: After a bit more research I found it is possible for a push notification- see my updated answer

Comment: OK I am seeing that. BTW don't remove information related to viber functionality :)

Comment: I have re-added the voip mode socket link, but removed the reference to Viber as that was guesswork on my part

Comment: If I am able to do this with global push notification. So I don't think I should use local notification. Is it right?. BTW I am not using VoIP Call facility in my app. So if I define it and it goes for review Will apple reject it?

Comment: I assumed you were creating a VoIP app because of the Viber example, but that may have been an incorrect assumption on my part.  Apple can definitely reject apps that misuse background modes, so best not to do that if you can achieve what you want with standard push notification

Answer (score 0):

Create/Edit this text file:

/YOURTHEME/Bundles/com.apple.springboard/en.lproj/SpringBoard.strings

And add this text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN""http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>AWAY_LOCK_LABEL</key>
<string>slide to unlock</string>
<key>POWER_DOWN_LOCK_LABEL</key>
<string>slide to shut down</string>
<key>SLIDE_TO_ANSWER</key>
<string>slide to answer</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Hope that helps

Taken from here.. 
http://modmyi.com/forums/winterboard/436941-slide-unlock-text-change.html#post2858481

Comment: This would require the device to be jailbroken and would change the "slide to answer" text for the device. The OP wants to change the subtitle on the app notification